# How can I prevent my tab-navigation from resetting on reload?

Tags: jquery, tabs, navigation

Should anyone out there be able to help me or point me to the right direction, I would appreciate it a lot!

I created a WordPress-Site for my uncle’s rental business. I’m still an amateur with Javascript/jQuery and PHP. You can see the page of a holiday apartment here:

[click here!](http://center-reisen.ch/en/wohnungen/ubersicht-2-personen/acimo-ch3906-300-15/)

As you can see in the center-top, there is a tab-menu showing all the apartments from this house in different categories/tabs (amount of persons).

Now, as a visitor chooses to click on f.e. a 5-Persons appartment, when he gets to the new site of the 5-persons apartment, the tab-navigation gets resetted and shows the 2 person category again. Here is the problem: logically thinking it should now show the 5 persons-tab, and not be resetted on every reload…

Is there a way to ask the database, what kind of apartment this is, so it can show the right tab?

The tab-navigation is created with the help of a theme-shortcode. Can the tab somehow stay on the same tab that was clicked instead of being resetted everytime?

How do I go about this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here's the minified javascript:

`(function(c){function p(d,b,a){var e=this,l=d.add(this),h=d.find(a.tabs),i=b.jquery?b:d.children(b),j;h.length||(h=d.children());i.length||(i=d.parent().find(b));i.length||(i=c(b));c.extend(this,{click:function(f,g){var k=h.eq(f);if(typeof f=="string"&&f.replace("#","")){k=h.filter("[href*="+f.replace("#","")+"]");f=Math.max(h.index(k),0)}if(a.rotate){var n=h.length-1;if(f<0)return e.click(n,g);if(f>n)return e.click(0,g)}if(!k.length){if(j>=0)return e;f=a.initialIndex;k=h.eq(f)}if(f===j)return e; g=g||c.Event();g.type="onBeforeClick";l.trigger(g,[f]);if(!g.isDefaultPrevented()){o[a.effect].call(e,f,function(){g.type="onClick";l.trigger(g,[f])});j=f;h.removeClass(a.current);k.addClass(a.current);return e}},getConf:function(){return a},getTabs:function(){return h},getPanes:function(){return i},getCurrentPane:function(){return i.eq(j)},getCurrentTab:function(){return h.eq(j)},getIndex:function(){return j},next:function(){return e.click(j+1)},prev:function(){return e.click(j-1)},destroy:function(){h.unbind(a.event).removeClass(a.current); i.find("a[href^=#]").unbind("click.T");return e}});c.each("onBeforeClick,onClick".split(","),function(f,g){c.isFunction(a[g])&&c(e).bind(g,a[g]);e[g]=function(k){k&&c(e).bind(g,k);return e}});if(a.history&&c.fn.history){c.tools.history.init(h);a.event="history"}h.each(function(f){c(this).bind(a.event,function(g){e.click(f,g);return g.preventDefault()})});i.find("a[href^=#]").bind("click.T",function(f){e.click(c(this).attr("href"),f)});if(location.hash&&a.tabs=="a"&&d.find("[href="+location.hash+"]").length)e.click(location.hash); else if(a.initialIndex===0||a.initialIndex>0)e.click(a.initialIndex)}c.tools=c.tools||{version:"1.2.5"};c.tools.tabs={conf:{tabs:"a",current:"current",onBeforeClick:null,onClick:null,effect:"default",initialIndex:0,event:"click",rotate:false,history:false},addEffect:function(d,b){o[d]=b}};var o={"default":function(d,b){this.getPanes().hide().eq(d).show();b.call()},fade:function(d,b){var a=this.getConf(),e=a.fadeOutSpeed,l=this.getPanes();e?l.fadeOut(e):l.hide();l.eq(d).fadeIn(a.fadeInSpeed,b)},slide:function(d, b){this.getPanes().slideUp(200);this.getPanes().eq(d).slideDown(400,b)},ajax:function(d,b){this.getPanes().eq(0).load(this.getTabs().eq(d).attr("href"),b)}},m;c.tools.tabs.addEffect("horizontal",function(d,b){m||(m=this.getPanes().eq(0).width());this.getCurrentPane().animate({width:0},function(){c(this).hide()});this.getPanes().eq(d).animate({width:m},function(){c(this).show();b.call()})});c.fn.tabs=function(d,b){var a=this.data("tabs");if(a){a.destroy();this.removeData("tabs")}if(c.isFunction(b))b= {onBeforeClick:b};b=c.extend({},c.tools.tabs.conf,b);this.each(function(){a=new p(c(this),d,b);c(this).data("tabs",a)});return b.api?a:this}})(jQuery);`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: How about using cookies?

Comment: I'm not asking for a solution to fix a bug or something like that on my website. I hope people who have experience with this can point me to the right way instead of how i can solve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Set cookies. Might be easier using jQuery: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I have found this post which shows me how to create that cookie... the problem is, I can't seem to decipher my minified javascript and don't know where I should put the cookie, so that the state gets saved onClick.

Comment: I posted the minified javascript above in my question... anyone able to decipher it and show me where I would have to put the cookie?